# ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment in Jade code

Tags: webpack, pug

I am using Webpack + `jade-loader` + `file-loader` to precompile some Jade code and store it in a module file. That part works just fine, but when I go to execute the function stored in said module, I get `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`. In particular, it is complaining about this `include`ed file:

```
meta(name="viewport", content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,width=device-width")
meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge,chrome=1")
meta(http-equiv="Content-Type", content="text/html; charset=utf-8")
```

on line two - the `http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"` piece. I am having a hard time figuring out why that line is a problem when it seems to process the first line perfectly. If I compile the code at run-time it works fine, so I do not think it has anything to do with malformed Jade (admittedly I am new to Jade).

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I am beginning to suspect the Jade template is being executed as JavaScript. Here is a basic Jade file with the `include` in question:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        block head
            include partials/meta.jade

    body
        p Hello Jade!
```

With `partials/meta.jade` being the code above. Here is the code that comes out:

```
var jade = require("/mnt/c/Users/jdawsocy/projects/jadeson/node_modules/jade/lib/runtime.js");

module.exports = function template(locals) {
var buf = [];
var jade_mixins = {};
var jade_interp;
;var locals_for_with = (locals || {});(function (undefined) {
buf.push("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>" + (null == (jade_interp = require("/mnt/c/Users/jdawsocy/projects/jadeson/src/jadeson/views/partials/meta.jade").call(this, locals)) ? "" : jade_interp) + "</head><body><p>Hello Jade!</p></body></html>");}.call(this,"undefined" in locals_for_with?locals_for_with.undefined:typeof undefined!=="undefined"?undefined:undefined));;return buf.join("");
}
```

It seems as though that `require` is actually trying to load the `meta.jade` file as though it is compiled similarly to the "Hello Jade" template.

I would prefer that be inlined instead of `require`d if possible. Otherwise, that template could be compiled but would obviously not end up in the same location with the same name. So, if the latter is the only option, I need a way to transform that `require`'s path to the path of the newly compiled file.

Comment: That's valid pug markup, so the issue is something else.

Comment: @sean You are right. I added some more code and details I have found that might be helpful in solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I ended up writing a script that compiled the Jade files using "client mode", which did the inlining for me. Unfortunately, I could not figure out how to do this with Webpack and the provided loaders alone.